# Cannot add foreign key to table

Tags: mysql

I have a problem to add foreign key to existing table, I always get error

```
ERROR 1005(HY000): Can't create table '#sql-a1f-b84' (errno: 150)
```

I tried like

```
ALTER TABLE alliances ADD CONSTRAINT fk_alliance_id FOREIGN KEY (alliance_id) references alliances(id);
```

When I do `DESCRIBE alliances;`

```
Field  Type    Null   Key  Default  Extra
id     int(11) NO     PRI  NULL     auto_increment
name   bigint(2) YES       NULL
```

When I do `DESCRIBE alliance_invitation;`

```
Field        Type    Null   Key  Default  Extra
id           int(11) NO     PRI  NULL     auto_increment
alliance_id  int(11) NO
```

Can anyone tell me what is a problem ?

Answer (score 3):

you need to first `CREATE INDEX` on your FK column `alliance_id`. Mysql needs an index to preexist in order to add a constraint on it.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
ALTER TABLE `alliance_invitation` ADD INDEX ( `alliance_id` );
ALTER TABLE `alliance_invitation` ADD FOREIGN KEY ( `alliance_id` ) 
REFERENCES `alliances` ( `id` ) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

You can change the CASCADE to anything else. more info [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)